# Query on sindice SPARQL endpoint

Tags: sparql, endpoint, http-status-code-504

I tried to make this query on http://sparql.sindice.com/

```
PREFIX rev: <http://purl.org/stuff/rev#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT *
WHERE
{
 ?thing rdfs:label ?name .
  ?thing rev:hasReview ?review .
 filter regex(str(?name), "harlem", "i")
} LIMIT 10
```

And it returns 504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time. 
What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of http://answers.semanticweb.com//questions/23639/make-sparql-on-the-sindice-endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a query that was too hard for the endpoint to answer in a timely fashion hence why you got a timeout response.  Note that there website states the following:

> all queries are time and resource limited. notice that this means that
>   sometime you will get incomplete or even no results. If this is
>   happening often for you or you really want to run more complex queries
>   please contact us

Your query essentially selects a vast swathe of data and then makes the engine run a regular expression over ever possible value which is extremely slow.

I believe Sindice use Virtuoso as their SPARQL implementation so you can cheat and use Virtuoso specific full text query extension like so:

```
PREFIX rev: <http://purl.org/stuff/rev#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT *
WHERE
{
  ?thing rdfs:label ?name .
  ?thing rev:hasReview ?review .
  ?name bif:contains "harlem" .
} 
LIMIT 10
```

However this query also seems to timeout, if you can add more conditions to constrain your query further you will have more chance of getting results in a timely fashion.

Comment: Yes, the Sindice endpoint is powered by Virtuoso, and the bif:contains predicate is definitely recommended.